How to prevent consumers of my component from using ::ng-deep to alter styles of my component
As part of the centralized component library I need to build, I want to instate a rule so that engineers are unable to morph the styles of the component using ::ng-deep. Does angular/scss/stylelint provide any safeguards to prevent this behavior?
I would prefer an scss/angular approach as opposed to a linting approach.
Most qns so far only refer to using ::ng-deep or avoiding ::ng-deep to manipulate styles of a component. Mine is the inverse.
I tried using ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom in angular's playground to see if adding this to a component would help. But so far it doesn't seem helpful (refer to screenshot) - screenshot of trying ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

Preventing usage of ::ng-deep doesn't really solve the problem, developers can just put the styles in the global styles instead. The only real solution would be Shadow DOM. It might be that you are running into the following issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35039

I am not aware of any in-built rules in eslint or tslint, but you can use a regex to match this word and throw an invalid error. You can experiment with the below package, which will warn the user, and prevent occurrences of its usage.
.eslintrc.json:
{
  "plugins": [
    "regex"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "regex/invalid": [
      "error", [
        "::ng-deep", // <- something like this. 
      ]
    ],
  }
}

eslint-plugin-regex
